# Is Lunar Horizon Glow still a thing? Has the "dust settled" on the topic?

Tags: the-moon, planetary-science, surveyor-program

The title gets its inspiration from [Is the Flyby Anomaly still a thing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23791/12102) but the topic is different.

The Lunar Horizon Glow is a phenomenon observed by some of the Surveyor missions. While the Sun is just below the horizon, a glow appears very close to the surface. The glow is thought to be forward-scattered light from dust electrostatically suspended just above the Moon's surface.

This was brought to my attention by comments below this [combative](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34730/12102) question which link to Phys.org's [Dust 'floats' above lunar surface—electrostatic dust transport reshapes surfaces of airless planetary bodies](https://phys.org/news/2016-12-lunar-surfaceelectrostatic-reshapes-surfaces-airless.html) which describes some recent work reported in Geophysical Research Letters: [Dust charging and transport on airless planetary bodies](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2016GL069491) which in turn references [Lunar surface: Dust dynamics and regolith mechanics](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2005RG000184) from which I've included the images below.

Has the "dust settled yet" on this topic? Has there been more recent, independent observations of the horizon glow? For example, the recent Chang'e 3 and 4 missions have had landers and rovers on the Moon with modern equipment, have they reported any similar observations? Or any other observations besides the Surveyor data?

[image: lunar horizon halo]

> Unprocessed images of lunar horizon glow with observation times in Greenwich mean time. The Surveyor 1 image and one intermediate Surveyor 7 image are not shown. Zodiacal light is evident in the Surveyor 5 and 6 images but not in the Surveyor 7 images, perhaps because of the different camera iris settings. Photographs from National Space Science Data Center.

[image: lunar horizon halo]

> Contrast enhanced and low‐pass‐filtered images of lunar horizon glow from (top) Surveyor 6 and (bottom) Surveyor 7. The apparent gap between the horizon glow and the lunar surface noted by Rennilson and Criswell [1974] can also be explained by forward scattering of light from the cloud itself to illuminate part of the lunar surface between the horizon and the spacecraft. Photographs from National Space Science Data Center.

Comment: Ironically, much of the impetus for the levitating dust theory seems to come from Apollo astronaut observations of the phenomenon from orbit.

Comment: @NathanTuggy if this visual phenomenon was seen by  Apollo astronauts, then that would certainly at least count as a "...more recent, independent observations of the horizon glow" (assuming it is more recent).